# Please explain tcp[13] & 4 == 4

Tags: networking, tcp, filter, wireshark, flags

Can someone explain what does this mean `tcp[13] & 4 == 4`?

I'm not sure how to explain this in Layman's term.

Comment: That the third bit from the right is true? I think we may need some more context for a meaningful answer.

Comment: These are TCP flags which are used to identify different sorts of traffic. e.g. tcp[13] & 4!=0 denotes RST packets. Idk about 4==4 though but it must also be an identifier for flag.

Answer (score 0):

Read the SYN capture tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 4 == 4', you’re saying find the 13th byte in the TCP header, and only grab packets where the flag in the 4th bit is equal to 4.
try this site it explains it quite well https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpflags/

Comment: Yes but what sort of packets are those where 4==4?

Comment: 4 != 0 would be all RST packets i would assume 4 == 4 is just looking for a flag, i'm a bit unsure.

Comment: @NSNoob That would depend on what the operator precedence for this language is...

Comment: 'tcp[13] & 4 == 4' is just another way of saying  'tcp[13] & 4 != 0'. So, as noted, this filter finds all the TCP RST packets.

Comment: `&` is of higher precedence than `==`, so the check is for packets where the 0x4 bit (RST) of the TCP flags (`tcp[13]`) (see [RFC 793 section 3.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#section-3.1)) is set.  As it's testing a single bit, `tcp[13] & 4 == 4` and `tcp[13] & 4 != 0` will, as willyo notes, have the same result - the result of `tcp[13] & 4` will either be 4 or 0.  The libpcap compiler generates slightly more efficient code for `tcp[13] & 4 != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

This comes a little late. The statement `tcp[13] & 4 == 4` essentially says the 13th byte (0 based) should have the TCP RESET bit (numeric value is 4) turned on (don't care about the other bits in this byte).

Hope the above helps you to understand it.